# remove minimum items from two list to make lists same

Tags: python, algorithm

I have two lists with same items and different orders.
for example:

```
a = [4, 2, 3, 1]
b = [2, 3, 1, 4]
```

Which item(s) should I remove to make lists same?
Here: `[4]` is an answer, so:

```
a = [2, 3, 1]
b = [2, 3, 1]
```

But `[2, 4]` or `[2, 3, 1]` are also answers, if I remove `[2, 3, 1]`:

```
a = [4]
b = [4]
```

I need to remove the minimum number of elements, here `[4]` is the optimal solution.

Another example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 1, 4, 3]
```

Possible answers:

```
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
```

Order of algorithm is unimportant.

Comment: The original lists are of the same size? Anyway probably you can adapt the [Levenshtein distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). You'll have to keep not only the number of insertions/removals/replacements but also the exact actions that were performed.

Comment: I dont think SO is a place to get your interview question answered.. we will be able to help you if you are stuck at some point.. consider showing us what you have tried, what approach you are thinking of..

Comment: Two lists are same size with same items but only different sorting.

Comment: If I use Levenshtein it returns number of movement but I don't need number of moves to make lists same. I need some deletions to do that.

Comment: I think I can test all subsets. first I can test subsets with length 1 and if lists are not same I try with subsets of length 2 and ... But I like a better algorithm.

Comment: I didn't say to use the levenshtein distance algorithm. I said you could adapt it to do what you want. Actually I think that if you adapt it you get something really similar to the LCS mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would certainly search for the longest common subsequence first (google LCS, many algorithms are available, e.g. on [algorithmist](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Longest_Common_Subsequence)), then if you remove the LCS elements from one of the original list you got the shortest list of elements to remove. In pseudocode :

```
lcs = LCS(a,b)
res = copy(a)
foreach element e in lcs
  remove(res,e)
return res
```

Comment: Urf, I was just about to hit post.  First sentences: "Say you have a longest common subsequence algorithm (not necessarily contiguous; subsequence, not substring).  That'll give you the maximum number you could keep, and so len(seq)-that will give you the minimum number you need to remove."